# The subgroup of isometries fixing a point is isomorphic to the orthogonal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry

How would I prove that for any arbitrary vector in a Euclidean space, the subgroup of isometries fixing that vector is isomorphic to O(U) via conjugation?
Should I use the first isomorphism theorem somehow, or just show it's a bijective homomorphism? 
Further, I don't even know how to do that. Clearly applying any conjugation is a homomorphism, but I don't know how to show it's a bijection, namely because I don't know what I'm mapping to what.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct an explicit isomorphism of groups. The word *conjugation* refers to conjugating the stabilizer of the given point by an isometry mapping it to the origin. The result of conjugation is the group of isometries fixing the origin, which is what the orthogonal group is.

---

Same with more symbols:

Let $E$ be the Euclidean space and fix a point $p\in E$. Let $\tau$  be the translation by $p$, so that $\tau(o)=p$. (Actually any isometry mapping $o$ to $p$ will do.) Observe that the following are equivalent:

1. $T$ is an isometry such that $Tp=p$
2. $T=\tau S\tau^{-1}$ where $S$ is an isometry such that $To=o$